# How to check if a URL is a valid RSS feed in PHP

Tags: php, rss

I have the following code:

```
    function parse() {
        $content = file_get_contents($this->feed);        
        $rss = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
        $rss_split = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
            $title = (string) $item->title; // Title
            $link = (string) $item->link; // Url Link            
            $content = $item->children('content', true)->encoded;
            preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+)[\'"].*>/i', $content, $image);
            $image = substr($image['src'], 0, strpos($image['src'], '"'));
            $rss_split[$i]['title'] = $title;
            $rss_split[$i]['link'] = $link;
            $rss_split[$i]['image'] = $image;
            $i++;
        }
        return $rss_split;
    }
```

Here, `$this->feed` contains the RSS feed's URL. The problem is I do not know how to validate the URL to be sure it is a valid RSS feed.

Comment: rss is just xml. if it's not a valid feed, then whatever you get back from the url won't validate as an xml/rss document.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To verify that it is XML:

```
function parse()
{
    $content = file_get_contents($this->feed); 
    try { $rss = new SimpleXmlElement($content); }
    catch(Exception $e){ /* the data provided is not valid XML */ return false; }
    // rest of your function goes here
```

Once you have verified that it is XML you have a couple of options:

1. you could check to make sure `isset($rss->channel->item)` existed and `$rss->channel->item->count()` > 0.
2. You can use `count($rss->xpath(/channel/item)) > 0`.

I'd use xpath, personally as I find it a little more obvious when reading the code.

---

### SIDE NOTE:

Seriously? You've already got XML object. Why are you using RegEx?

Don't do this:

```
preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+)[\'"].*>/i', $content, $image);
```

When this is a valid option:

```
$g = $item->xpath('//img'); $g[0]->attributes()->src;
```

Comment: If I am providing wrong url then it not executing this line `$rss = new SimpleXmlElement($content);` and rest of below line after it

Comment: @kj7 See the edit. The reason it will stop executing is that SimpleXmlElement will trigger an exception if it is not provided with something which can be converted to XML.

Comment: If the xml file is too big, its takes too much time to read the whole file, any other option to check this quickly.

Comment: @cwallenpoole can you please answer the above question thanks

Comment: @nit3ch Not if you want to check the integrity of the file as a whole. That requires ingesting the file as a whole.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Actually i don't want to validate the whole xml file, i just want to check whether it is a xml file or not and i don't want to do it by just checking the extension.

Comment: @nit3ch You need to ask a separate question about that then.

Comment: `count($rss->xpath(/channel/item)) > 0` should be `count($rss->xpath('/rss/channel/item')) > 0`

Answer (score 1):

May this will helpfull to you.

```
?php

function validateFeed( $sFeedURL )
{

$sValidator = 'http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=';

if( $sValidationResponse = @file_get_contents($sValidator . urlencode($sFeedURL)) )
{
    if( stristr( $sValidationResponse , 'This is a valid RSS feed' ) !== false )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$rss = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
if($rss)
{
     //your code
}
else
{ return false; }
```